# Can't Inject DAO to Repository for some reason

Tags: android, dagger-hilt

Here is the codebase:

**Database**

```
@Database(
    entities = [
        User::class,
        AlphabetLesson::class,
        PhrasesLesson::class
    ],
    version = 1,
    exportSchema = false
)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun userDao(): UserDao
    abstract fun alphabetLessonDao(): AlphabetLessonDao
    abstract fun phrasesLessonDao(): PhrasesLessonDao

    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: AppDatabase? = null

        fun getDatabase(context: Context): AppDatabase {
            return INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
                Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    AppDatabase::class.java,
                    "app_database.db"
                )
                .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                .createFromAsset("database.db")
                .build()
                .also {INSTANCE = it}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**DAO**

```
@Dao
interface UserDao {

    @Query("SELECT * from user")
    fun selectAllUsers(): Flow<List<User>>

    @Query("SELECT * from user WHERE id = :userID")
    fun selectUserById(userID: Int): Flow<User>

    @Query("SELECT COUNT(*) from user")
    fun countUsers(): Flow<Int>

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insertUser(user: User)

    @Update
    suspend fun updateUser(user: User)

    @Query("UPDATE user SET user_name = :userName WHERE id = :userID")
    suspend fun updateUserName(userName: String?, userID: Int)

    @Query("UPDATE user SET is_new_user = :boolValue WHERE id = :userID")
    suspend fun updateUserStatus(boolValue: Int, userID: Int)

    @Query("UPDATE user SET progression_level = :userLevel WHERE id = :userID")
    suspend fun updateUserProgressionLevel(userLevel: Int, userID: Int)

    @Delete
    suspend fun deleteUser(user: User)
}
```

**Repository**

```
@WorkerThread
class UserRepository @Inject constructor(
     private val dao: UserDao
) {
    val allUsers: Flow<List<User>> = dao.selectAllUsers()

    fun getUserByID(userID: Int): Flow<User> {
        return dao.selectUserById(userID)
    }

    fun isThereNoUser(): Flow<Boolean> = flow {
        val numberOfUsers: Int? = dao.countUsers().firstOrNull()
        var isUserEmpty = true

        if (numberOfUsers == 0) {
            isUserEmpty = true
        } else if (numberOfUsers != 0) {
            isUserEmpty = false
        }
        emit(isUserEmpty)
    }

    suspend fun insertUser(user: User) {
        dao.insertUser(user)
    }

    suspend fun insertNewUser(id: Int, name: String) {
        val user = User(
            id,
            name,
            0,
            1
        )
        dao.insertUser(user)
    }

    suspend fun updateUser(user: User) {
        dao.updateUser(user)
    }

    suspend fun updateUserNameWithID(userName: String?, userID: Int) {
        dao.updateUserName(userName, userID)
    }

    suspend fun updateUserStatusWithID(boolValue: Int, userID: Int) {
        dao.updateUserStatus(boolValue, userID)
    }

    suspend fun updateUserLevelWithID(userLevel: Int, userID: Int) {
        dao.updateUserProgressionLevel(userLevel, userID)
    }

    suspend fun deleteUser(user: User) {
        dao.deleteUser(user)
    }
}
```

**Data Module**

```
package com.ruralnative.handsy.di

import android.content.Context
import com.ruralnative.handsy.data.AppDatabase
import com.ruralnative.handsy.data.dao.AlphabetLessonDao
import com.ruralnative.handsy.data.dao.PhrasesLessonDao
import com.ruralnative.handsy.data.dao.UserDao
import com.ruralnative.handsy.data.repository.AlphabetLessonRepository
import com.ruralnative.handsy.data.repository.PhrasesLessonRepository
import com.ruralnative.handsy.data.repository.UserRepository
import com.ruralnative.handsy.di.qualifiers.AlphabetDAO
import com.ruralnative.handsy.di.qualifiers.AlphabetRepo
import com.ruralnative.handsy.di.qualifiers.Database
import com.ruralnative.handsy.di.qualifiers.PhrasesDAO
import com.ruralnative.handsy.di.qualifiers.PhrasesRepo
import com.ruralnative.handsy.di.qualifiers.UserDAO
import com.ruralnative.handsy.di.qualifiers.UserRepo
import dagger.Module
import dagger.Provides
import dagger.hilt.InstallIn
import dagger.hilt.android.qualifiers.ApplicationContext
import dagger.hilt.components.SingletonComponent
import javax.inject.Singleton

@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object DataModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @Database
    fun provideLocalDatabase(
        @ApplicationContext context: Context
    ): AppDatabase {
       return AppDatabase.getDatabase(context)
    }

    @Provides
    @AlphabetDAO
    fun provideAlphabetLessonDao(
        @Database database: AppDatabase
    ): AlphabetLessonDao = database.alphabetLessonDao()

    @Provides
    @PhrasesDAO
    fun providePhrasesLessonDao(
        @Database database: AppDatabase
    ): PhrasesLessonDao = database.phrasesLessonDao()

    @Provides
    @UserDAO
    fun provideUserDao(
        @Database database: AppDatabase
    ): UserDao = database.userDao()

    @Provides
    @AlphabetRepo
    fun provideAlphabetLessonRepository(
        @AlphabetDAO dao: AlphabetLessonDao
    ): AlphabetLessonRepository = AlphabetLessonRepository(dao)

    @Provides
    @PhrasesRepo
    fun providePhrasesLessonRepository(
        @PhrasesDAO dao: PhrasesLessonDao
    ): PhrasesLessonRepository = PhrasesLessonRepository(dao)

    @Provides
    @UserRepo
    fun provideUserRepository(
        @UserDAO dao: UserDao
    ): UserRepository = UserRepository(dao)
}
```

Somehow, whenever I build the project it says it can't inject the DAO to the Repository. Note that I actually tested this before and it works, even the Repository. Now it doesn't. It is becoming frustrating. Please help.

I tried checking the Modules and it is all good. I also tried cleaning the Android project and rebuild it, still no result.